# Are there any single-server anti-virus solutions for Windows?

Tags: windows, antivirus, windows-server

Currently, I'm maintaining three (intentionally) independent Windows 2012 web servers.

I'm using *Sophos Server Endpoint Protection* on each server.

What bothers me is that Sophos (and all other anti-virus server solutions I'm aware of) seems to be intended to be used in large server environments only.

I.e. they have a central management tool, a deployment agent, clients for each computer, etc.

Since I *intentionally* do not want to connect my servers to each other, I'm forced to install the full management tools on each server instead of just a simple, unattended, anti-virus tool.

**My question is:**

Are there any commercial server-grade anti-virus tools that are designed to run on a single server only?